# How to backup and restore HANA schema correctly?

Tags: hana, database-backups, database-restore, hana-studio

Version of SAP HANA Studio is 2.3.37

Require the correct steps to perform backup and recovery of a specific schema in SAP HANA STUDIO

Steps performed:

1. For backup, I selected the schema (Right Click->Export).
   2.Selected the folder i wanted to take backup and clicked on "Finish".

Is this the right way of taking the schema backup??
If not, pls specify the correct way to tae backup.
Also pls specify the steps to perform recovery.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SQLScript EXPORT command:

```
EXPORT "HD_SCHEMA"."*" AS BINARY INTO '/usr/sap/HDB/HDB00/SCHEMATA' WITH REPLACE THREADS 8
```

however it is basically the same as the manual way you use. Though in HANA Studio export you can choose export in a more handy and straightforward way, which is a plus.

So you are doing it right.